# Reset the database after 3 hrs & make it behave as a new database through php script

Tags: php, mysql

How to reset the database after 3 hrs & make it behave as a new database through php script

Comment: I cannot drop the database as its of other application but want to reset it by simply delete data within the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way would be to have a `cron` job that executes every three hours and calls mysql with "clean" database set up. The crontab set up would be something along the lines of:

`* */03 * * * mysql -u XXX -pXXX < clean_database.sql`

However, the "clean_database.sql" file would need to use "`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` ..." **for each of the tables you want to reset**. That said, you can simply use `mysqldump` with a "known good" version of the database to create this file. (You'll need to add a "`use <database name>;`" statement at the top that said.)

Comment: how to set crontab through php script

Comment: @Angelin Nadar - You don't, you use the Unix 'crontab -e' command for the appropriate user. (I presume you're running under Unix/Linux, etc.)

Comment: @Angelin Nadar No problems - hope you get it all working properly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to drop the database and recreate it using your create scripts. If you don't have create scripts you can get them by making a dump of your database.

---

To delete the data in each table *without* dropping the tables you can use the [`TRUNCATE TABLE tablename`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) command on each table.

If you don't have permission to use `TRUNCATE` you can use `DELETE FROM tablename` without a WHERE clause.

Note that if you have foreign key constraints you may have to run the statements in a specific order to avoid violating these constraints.

To get a list of all tables you can use `SHOW TABLES`.

Comment: The problem with not having the permission to `TRUNCATE` is that `DELETE FROM table` doesn't reset (e.g.) cardinality of `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields...

Answer (score 1):

steps to do:

1. connect to database server
2. select database
3. `mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");`
4. read in array or object
5. `foreach($tables as $tableName)` of the item `mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE $tableName")`

I hope the principle is clean to you ;-)

Comment: gd these are steps iam going to follow in php scripts .how to run this through script after 3 hrs according to server time

Comment: The best would be to add an entry to the crontab if that is possible ;-). Otherwise there are online services which offer "remote cron jobs" - that means, their service visits a url and so it will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query('DROP DATABASE yourdatabase');
mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE yourdatabase');
mysql_query('CREATE TABLE yourdatabase.sometable ...'); // etc.
```

This will drop the database, and create it anew. You can then use the `CREATE TABLE` syntax to recreate the tables - note that as this script has significant powers, you should consider creating a special mySQL user for it, one that's not used during normal operations.